# Что нужно, чтобы организовать бюджетный SIM хаб с GSM-шлюзом?

Tags: связь

Нужна система для программного принятия СМС с множества сим-карт. Какое оборудование нужно? Какое конкретное можно использовать как бюджетный вариант? Есть навыки в пайке :), но при желании можно и научиться делать платы. Сервисы приема СМС не предлагать.

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что это будет usb хаб с кучей GSM модемов.

Comment: А они работают обычно через симуляцию COM порта (нужно ведь будет посылать AT команды для чтения-отправки смс). А больше 8 штук com портов в одной системе (даже эмуляторов) обычно не заводиться.

Comment: Может есть какая-то возможность сделать один хаб с множеством разъемов под сим-карты, которые будут соединены с gsm модемом, который можно будет настраивать на конкретную карту? Я в этом совсем новичек, так что понятия не имею что там и как :) Но задача есть и ее нужно решить.

Comment: Для чего, сколько сим-карт, какой бюджет?

Comment: Для приема смс исключительно(отправка, вызовы не нужны). Сим 1000+. Бюджет будет зависеть от стоимости всех компонентов, но чем меньше он будет - тем лучше.